# PHP: Functions not working

Tags: php, html, function

Good afternoon guys! I’ve been trying to call a function and it just doesn’t seem to work.

So, this is the code I’ve got:

```
<? 
if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
$acess_level = 4;
if (!isset($_SESSION['UserID']) OR ($_SESSION['UserAL'] < $acess_level)) {
    session_destroy();
    header("Location: login"); exit;
}


$tlang = $_SESSION['lang'];
$level = $_SESSION['UserAL'];
include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/inside/functions.php");
$check = "adv";

function doLang()
{
  if ($tlang == 'en') {echo "Advanced Tutorials";} 
  if ($tlang == 'br') {echo "Tutoriais Avançados";} 
  if ($tlang == 'es') {echo "Tutoriales Avanzados";} 
  if ($tlang == 'fr') {echo "Tutos avancés";} 
  if ($tlang == 'id') {echo "Pelatihan dengan cara proffesional";} 
  if ($tlang == 'fi') {echo "Edistyneempiä oppaita";} 
  if ($tlang == 'tr') {echo "Gelişmiş Kılavuzlar";}
}

doLang();
echo "test".doLang()."test"; ?>
```

The "session" part is working correctly so I guess there ain’t no typo/problem there at all. So, basically, the doLang() function checks what language the user is using and then echos the ‘‘right’’ language, as you can see. If I use something like this:

```
<?
  if ($tlang == 'en') {echo "Advanced Tutorials";} 
  if ($tlang == 'br') {echo "Tutoriais Avançados";} 
  if ($tlang == 'es') {echo "Tutoriales Avanzados";} 
  if ($tlang == 'fr') {echo "Tutos avancés";} 
  if ($tlang == 'id') {echo "Pelatihan dengan cara proffesional";} 
  if ($tlang == 'fi') {echo "Edistyneempiä oppaita";} 
  if ($tlang == 'tr') {echo "Gelişmiş Kılavuzlar";}
?>
```

It works like a charm but if I use a function instead it just doesn’t work. Am I missing something, did I do something wrong? Thanks for your attention!

Comment: You need to pass $tLang as an argument to the function - read about [variable scope](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: also, consider doing a switch() statement.

Comment: And `return` the value instead of echoing it.

Comment: @ChristianGärtner Sorry but could you teach me how to return it? @Robbert’s  return function is not working :\

Comment: @MisaelVergara, I fixed the function.  I left out some quotes.

Answer (score 6):

$tLang is not in the scope of the function.  You need to either pass the variable to the function

```
function doLang($tLang) {
   ...
}
```

or use the global statement

```
function doLang() {
   global $tLang

   ....
}
```

The first method is the preferred method.

You really should consider changing the way you use this function.  To clean it up, I would use a switch statement to make the flow a little nicer and I would return the value instead of echoing the result.  Right now, since you're calling the function during an echo statement (`echo "test".doLang()."test"`), your function works, but if you were to ever use it in a variable assignment (`$var = "text".doLang()."text"`), your function would not work

```
function doLang($tLang)
{
   $val = "";
   switch($tLang) {
     case "br":
       $val = "Tutoriais Avançados"
       break;
     case "es":
       $val = "Tutoriales Avanzados";
       break;
     case "fr":
       $val = "Tutos avancés";
       break;
     case "id":
       $val = "Pelatihan dengan cara proffesional";
       break;
     case "fi":
       $val = "Edistyneempiä oppaita";
       break;
     case "tr":
       $val = "Gelişmiş Kılavuzlar";
       break;
     default:
       $val = "Advanced Tutorials";
       break;
   }
   return $val;
}
```

Using the default statement ensures that `$val` always has a value to return.

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
function doLang($tlang)
{
  if ($tlang == 'en') { echo "Advanced Tutorials"; } 
  if ($tlang == 'br') { echo "Tutoriais Avançados"; } 
  if ($tlang == 'es') { echo "Tutoriales Avanzados"; } 
  if ($tlang == 'fr') { echo "Tutos avancés"; } 
  if ($tlang == 'id') { echo "Pelatihan dengan cara proffesional"; } 
  if ($tlang == 'fi') { echo "Edistyneempiä oppaita"; } 
  if ($tlang == 'tr') { echo "Gelişmiş Kılavuzlar"; }
}

doLang($tlang);
?>
```

Comment: Note that if you're echoing the result of the function, you should probably return from rather than echo in the function

Comment: @MarkBaker : Yeah i had copied entire from the original post.. removed..

Comment: Just hope the OP isn't offering advanced tutorials in PHP

Comment: @MarkBaker :.. :)..haha,, no..